# Generating wealth distribution from return parameters (mean, SD)

Tags: lognormal

Super basic question here!

Suppose I start with $100 and invest in an asset with known mean (arithmetic) return and standard deviation of returns.

I'm interested in plotting the distribution of my ending wealth over varying time frames in Excel. My understanding is that the distribution will be lognormal. For example, I'd get one distribution for a 1-year holding period and another distribution for a 20-year holding period.

What would be the right way to set this up in Excel?

Answer (score 1):

Very easily. See screenshots below:

[image]

This is the only formula you need:

[image]

You can do as many simulations you want and then just plot the cumulative distribution.

Comment: Thanks so much! two follow up questions:
1) instead of adding in $D$3, could you specify a mean within the NORMINV() function? (where now you have 0)
2) given we're talking about a stock return here, it seems like you'd want to use: D7*(1+MAX(NORMINV(...),-1) to prevent losing more than 100%

Comment: You can specify the mean on the norminv, yes. Ideally to avoid losing more than 100%, you should specify the returns in logs.

Comment: how would you adapt the spreadsheet example to specify the returns in logs?

Comment: =+D7*(EXP(\$D\$3+NORMINV(RAND(),0,\$D\$4)))

Comment: i assume you'd need to convert mu to ln(1.05) right? how would you need to update the STD?

Comment: You don't. They just become growth of the return and standard deviation of the log return